# How to setup Metamask locally in my system?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, metamask

I'm setting up Metamask locally. I have downloaded the repository from https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension.

When I tried to load extension it failed due to the following errors:

```
   require is not define at background.js:6
   WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:35729/livereload' failed: Error 
   in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Comment: do you actually have a local rpc server? like ganache?

Comment: @twxia Does that have anything to do with it? This seems to be a compilation issue, not a RPC issue.

Comment: I don't know if you have solve it. But I had the same issue and the solution was to create an ID from infura.io and adding it to the INFURA_PROJECT_ID to my project in the .metamsaksrc file.